# List<>.FindAll with few conditions

Tags: c#

There's some faster method than this to find all person with some conditions?

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(phone))
{
      List<Person> newList = List.FindAll(s => s.Name == name && s.Surname == lastname && s.Phone == phone);
}
else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname))
{
      List<Person> newList = List.FindAll(s => s.Name == name && s.Surname == lastname);
}
```

etc.

Comment: Probably, using loops, though the more matches you get the longer this would take (it's quicker to NOT match)

Comment: Where is the data coming from?  Is it always in memory?  Are you accessing from a database, etc?

Comment: Do you really need this faster, or just easier to maintain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your version is likely the *fastest* option at runtime.  The `List<T>.FindAll` predicate you created is efficient, since it does the fewest checks.

However, you could use LINQ to make the code simpler and more maintainable:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = List; // Start with no filters

// Add filters - just chaining as needed
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(name) && !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(lastname))
{
    people = people.Where(s => s.Name == name && s.Surname == lastname);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(phone))
        people = people.Where(s => s.Phone == phone);
}

//... Add as many as you want

List<Person> newList = people.ToList(); // Evaluate at the end
```

This will be far more maintainable, and likely be "fast enough", since filtering is typically not done in a tight loop.

Comment: I'd also use something like `PredicateBuilder` (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build the filter expression.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot This is all in-memory, so that's not needed.  That being said, using standard queryables with EF and similar should be just as efficient.  PredicateBuilder is nice, but only if you need to build the filters off strings, not from code with known variable names.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot PredicateBuilder is a bit overkill for this problem. You can just change the query in an `if` block because both evaluate to an `IQueryable<Person>` / `IEnumerable<Person>`.

Comment: Just be careful: this version performs a different function then the original.

Comment: @ChrisPitman Good point - just made it the same result as the original now

Answer (score 3):

I'd rewrite this way just to make it easier to read:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname)) {
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(phone))
     {
           List<Person> newList = List.FindAll(s => s.Name == name && s.Surname == lastname && s.Phone == phone);
     }
     else 
     {
          List<Person> newList = List.FindAll(s => s.Name == name && s.Surname == lastname);
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 it also avoids re-evaluating the null/empty checks on `name` and `lastname` in the `else if` from the original post